# Simple login for private user-files

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

I want to create a simple login with only a few hard-coded username/password combos which gives access to individual private directories with files that I upload. (mysite.com/user1/, mysite.com/anotheruser/...)

Below are the contents of my mylogin.php.

What approaches are there for me to "password protect" files for download only from this page and by their respective users?  The information will not be terribly sensitive, but it should be somewhat secure.

```
<?php   //List of users and their passwords
$users = array(
    "myusername" => "mYpaSSw0rd2011",
    "anothername" => "password2"
);?>

<html>
<head><title>Private Login</title></head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="mylogin.php">
      Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="15" /><br />
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="15" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>

<?php //check username:password combo
if ( isset($_POST["username"]) && $_POST["username"] != "" && ($users[$_POST["username"]] == $_POST["password"]) 
    //*******************************************************
    //list (private) files in mysite.com/username's directory
    //*******************************************************    
}?>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find this very useful:

> header('Content-disposition:attachment; filename.pdf');

Just read the file (using readfile for example), dump the data and set the header as an attachement.

Store the originals where that cannot be accessed by http (or use an HTACCESS to protect them).

Comment: allright! I was able to get it working.  It took a minute to wrap my head around the header() function and file/directory functions but your advice definitely got me pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be appropriate to post the code I ended up using for future reference.  I ended up splitting the project into 3 different files (as well as directories for the users).

Within the user directories I placed .htaccess files with `<Files *>Deny from all</Files>` so that their files are protected.

Also, I know I did some of this stuff pretty poorly.  I started to use sessions, but I was having difficulty getting it to work right.  You can see some of the remnants in the code.  Any help refactoring would be greatly appreciated.

I cut out some markup to make the following code more readable.

```
==================================================================
index.php=========================================================
==================================================================

    <form method="POST" action="userview.php">
      Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="15" /><br />
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="15" /><br />  
      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>

==================================================================    
userview.php======================================================
==================================================================

<?php 
    //List of users and their passwords
    $users = array(
        "myusername" => "mYpaSSw0rd2011",
        "anothername" => "password2",
    );

    //Check posted user:pass & start session (or die on mismatch)
        //****Session currently doesn't carry over to download.php.  I am re-posting username with a hidden form field****
    if ( isset($_POST["username"]) && $_POST["username"] != "" && ($users[$_POST["username"]] == $_POST["password"])) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST["username"];
    } else die("incorrect login");
?>

<html><head><title><?php echo $_POST["username"] ?>'s Files</title></head><body>
<h1>Contents of <?php echo $_POST["username"] ?>'s Directory:</h1>

<?php 
    $handle = opendir( $_SESSION['user'] . '/' );
    if ($handle) { //display directory contents within a radio button list.
        echo '<form method="POST" action="download.php">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="user" value="' . $_SESSION['user'] . '">';
        echo '<fieldset>';
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if (substr($file, 0, 1) !== ".")
                echo 
                    "<label><input type=\"radio\" name=\"dlfile\" value=\"$file\" /> $file",  "</label><br />\n";
        }
        closedir($handle);
        echo '</fieldset><br /><input type="submit" value="Download" /></form>' , "\n\n";
    } else die("error:  Please contact administrator");
?>
</body></html>

==================================================================
download.php======================================================
==================================================================

<?php 
if ( isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['dlfile'])) {
    $file = $_POST['user'] . "/" . $_POST['dlfile'];
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

?>